# How to display images using Switch statement?

Tags: javascript, html, github, switch-statement

I'm working on a Mass Effect personality quiz that has been adapted from the [EasyDamus D&D quiz](http://easydamus.com/character.html) from the 90s, and I'm having trouble with the results page. Namely, I'm trying to include an image to match each result, but I don't know how to do so when the code implements the results using a switch statement. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
var win = window.open("", "win","width=900,height=550,top=25,left=50,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=yes");

with (win.document) {
    open("text/html", "replace");
        
    write("<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='index.css'><title>Your Results Are In!\<\/title>\<\/head>");
            write("<body text='#FFFFFF' font-family='massEffect' link='#5555FF' vlink='#6666EE' bgcolor='#F2ECDA' background='images/space.png'>");

    write("<center><h2><b><font color='#FFFFFF'>You Are A:\<\/font>\<\/b>\<\/h2>\<\/center>");
    write("<br><center><h1><b>");
            
    
    switch (race) {
        case "human": write("Human\<\/b> "); break;
        case "asari": write("Asari\<\/b> "); break;
        case "turian": write("Turian\<\/b> "); break;
        case "salarian": write("Salarian\<\/b> "); break;
        case "krogan": write("Krogan\<\/b> "); break;
        case "quarian": write("Quarian\<\/b> "); break;
        case "geth": write("Geth\<\/b> "); break;
        case "volus": write("Volus\<\/b> "); break;
        case "rachni": write("Rachni\<\/b> "); break;
        case "batarian": write("Batarian\<\/b> "); }

    switch (primclass) {
        case "soldier": write(" Soldier"); break;
        case "infiltrator": write(" Infiltrator"); break;
        case "engineer": write(" Engineer"); break;
        case "adept": write(" Adept"); break;
        case "sentinel": write(" Sentinel"); break;
        case "vanguard": write(" Vanguard"); }

    switch (secclass) {
        case "soldier": write("/Soldier"); break;
        case "infiltrator": write("/infiltrator"); break;
        case "engineer": write("/Engineer"); break;
        case "adept": write("/Adept"); break;
        case "sentinel": write("/Sentinel"); break;
        case "none": write(""); break;
        case "vanguard": write("/Vanguard"); }



write("<br><h2><br>Race:<br></h2>");

    switch (race) {
    case "human": `
```

The last line is the flavor text for each result, and while there's no issue with how it displays, I'm trying to find a way to have an image precede it. I have the pictures available, most of them in array called from a local folder. What would be the best way to have the images appear?

I've searched for solutions for a few weeks, most of which recommend event listeners, but I haven't been able to get it to work for me.

Comment: This uses some very old JavaScript features that are now likely to be poorly supported by modern browsers, e.g. `with`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with , `document.write()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, as I mentioned before the code was adapted from a site that originated in the 90s. I'm still new to coding so I'm not sure what the best way to update it would be.

Answer (score 0):

This code does a lot of stuff. First of all with switch statement, it should set up some variable for a particular case. Also its always a good practice to provide a `default` case for each switch-statement.

```
function decideOnRace(race) {
    let result = '';
    switch (race) {
        case "human":
            result = "Human\<\/b> ";
            break;
        default:
            result = 'something else";
            break;
    }
}

// place this accordingly
const raceTextToWrite = decideOnRace(race);
write(raceTextToWrite);
```

Following this practice for all the different cases should help you progress e.g., for secclass, primclass, etc.

Comment: I think I get it, and the switch statements now have the right syntax, but I don't know how const plays into it? The switch statements that I listed in my snippet are for determining the heading, eg. "Salarian Adept", following by the text explaining the race and class in subsequent paragraphs. If I'm interpreting it correctly,the last three lines of your suggestion are for implementing the flavor text, but if so I'm not sure where in the function to put it. Currently, I have my flavor text coming towards the end of my snippet, in a write statement after case "human"